# Cant remove windows partition from mac(not BOOTCAMP)

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

I have a windows partition(not a bootcamp one) and would like to remove it.This was obviously not possible with bootcamp.I tried using Disk Utility but all buttons there are inactive.
[image]

I have programs like NTFS 3G,reFit installed.Any way to remove windows now?

Comment: What happens if you select the windows partition, you currently have selected the OSX one which you can't alter

Comment: @Mark same thing....it shows 34 GB and I cant edit anything...

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of that

Comment: Disk Utility does NOT support live partitioning, though you may be able to do this via Terminal.

Answer (score 5):

I just had a similar issue and solved it by following [@VDR's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122850) but it required slight modifications.

Open Terminal and run

```
$diskutil list
```

diskutil will return something similar to

/dev/disk0

```
:                       TYPE NAME                   SIZE      IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk0    
1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1 
2:                  Apple_HFS MountainLion            64.0 GB    disk0s2
3:       Microsoft Basic Data                         31.8 GB    disk0s3
4: 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649               1.0 MB     disk0s4
5: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               14.7 GB    disk0s5
6:                 Linux Swap                         17.2 GB    disk0s6
```

/dev/disk1...

The NTFS volume I want removed is at 3, run

`$diskutil **eraseVolume** JHFS+ old_win /dev/disk0s3`

You'll see output similar to...

```
Started erase on disk0s3
Unmounting disk
Erasing
Initialized /dev/rdisk0s3 as a 29 GB HFS Plus volume with a 8192k journal
Mounting disk
Finished erase on disk0s3 old_win
```

Your empty volume will now be manageable from the graphical Disk Utility app.

Answer (score 0):

One of the following three methods should work:

1) Boot into Recovery Mode and use Disk Utility from there. You should be able to modify or delete the NTFS partition on the main hard drive.

2) Boot your Mac from an external hard drive that has a bootable installation of Mac OS X on it, and run Disk Utility from there.

3) Put your Mac in Target Disk Mode and connect it via FireWire or Thunderbolt cable to another Mac. Run Disk Utility from the other Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try Formatting partition using below commands:

Open Terminal and run

```
$ diskutil list
```

this will show the list of partitions available in your computer and then run

```
$diskutil erasedisk JHFS+ SecondPartition <Partition which you want to format eg: /dev/disk2>
```

Where "SecondPartition" is the partition name it assigns after formatting and
"JHFS+" is the partition type - Journaled HFS+ Partition